# Why are the complex numbers printed here incorrect?

Tags: c++, class, complex-numbers

I am trying to complete a c++ assignment code of operating with complex numbers. The logic I have used in the operations is pretty much alright, but I cant get the output to come out as I want it. It must be a logical error but I am just not getting it.

I have tried constructors, parameterized and more, but I am just not getting it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{
     int r, i;
public:
    int Read()
    {
        cout << "Enter Real part" << endl;
        cin >> r;
        cout << "Enter Imaginary part" << endl;
        cin >> i;
        return 0;
    }

    complex Add(complex A, complex B)
    {
        complex sum;
        sum.r = A.r + B.r;
        sum.i = A.i + B.i;
        return sum;
    }
    complex Subtract(complex A, complex B)
    {
        complex diff;
        diff.r = A.r - B.r;
        diff.i = A.i - B.i;
        return diff;
    }
    complex Multiply(complex A, complex B)
    {
        complex prod;
        prod.r = A.r*B.r + A.i*B.i*(-1);
        prod.i = A.r*B.i + B.r*A.i;
        return prod;
    }
    complex Divide(complex A, complex B)
    {
        complex c_B; //conjugate of complex number B
        c_B.r = B.r;
        c_B.i = -B.i;
        complex quotient;
        complex numerator;
        complex denominator;
        numerator.Multiply(A, c_B);
        denominator.Multiply(B, c_B);
        int commonDenom = denominator.r + denominator.i;
        quotient.r = numerator.r / commonDenom;
        quotient.i = numerator.i / commonDenom;
        return quotient;
    }

    int Display()
    {
        cout << r << "+" << i << "i" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

};

int main()
{
    complex a, b, c;
    cout << "Enter first complex number" << endl;
    a.Read();
    cout << "Enter second complex number" << endl;
    b.Read();
    c.Add(a, b);
    c.Display();
    c.Multiply(a, b);
    c.Display();



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}





the expected output on input of 1+2i and 2+3i should be
3+5i
8+i

but output is
-858993460+-858993460i
-858993460+-858993460i
```

Comment: You have misunderstandings about how methods work. E.g. your `Add` method is called on `c` object, but you never access it, you never write to it, instead you create a `sum`, return it and throw it away. The reason for the garbage outputs is that you never initialized `r,i` inside the `c` instance.

Comment: *I have tried constructors* -- Your code shows no attempt of this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did the constructor thing after I posted, and I am still very new to this, so I'm sorry but I am very confused haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
c.Add(a, b);
c.Display(); // <- Here
```

Here’s something to think about: which complex number are you displaying here?

Take a look at your `Add` function. Notice that calling `c.Add(a, b)` does not actually set `c` equal to the sum of `a` and `b`. Instead, it essentially ignores `c` (look over the code - notice that you never read or write any fields of the receiver object) and then produces a new complex number equal to `a + b`. As a result, when you call `c.Display()`, you’re not printing the sum. Instead, you’re taking `c`, which never had its data members initialized, and printing out its value.

There are several different strategies you can use to fix this. Fundamentally, I’d look back over how you’ve defined `Add` and the other member functions that compute on complex numbers. If those member functions don’t use the receiver object, then consider either

1. Making them `static` or free functions so that they just operate on their two arguments, not two arguments plus an implicit `this` argument, or
2. Make them take exactly one parameter, with the two complex numbers operated on being the receiver object and the parameter. You then have a choice of whether to make those functions modify the receiver or return new values.

Once you’ve decided how you want to address that above issue, go back and look at the code you’ve written to add and print values. You may need to introduce more variables to explicitly capture the sums, differences, etc. of the operations you’ve performed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is really helpful, but as I am still a beginner I can't translate whatever you said in code, can you please help me by giving me an example?

Comment: no need, turns out all I had to do was instead of `c.Add(a, b);` I had to do `c=c.Add(a, b);`